# Where to uplaod Magento Extension Package files in Magento Connect Extension Submission?

Tags: magento

I have created new magento extension myself. i have created package.xml file and Extension Package file in my Magento admin panel.

After creating extension package file, i have submitted the extension information in magentocommcerce.com using my login credentials. In this case i have filled extension information and uploaded extension icons & screen shots.

**Should I upload those paid extension package files?** 
**If so where Should I upload?**

I dont see any option for uploading these package files in magentocommece.com.

```
Note : My extension is a paid version.
```

**Can any one point out me where to upload package files during magento extension submission?**
OR
**Did I missed anything? Is the uploading only for free extensions or paid versions as well?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please see here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/create_your_extension/

and this pdf in particular:
http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/packagingmagentoconnectextensions6%200.pdf

You upload your extension as normal. A free extension can become paid and vice versa, decided if it is free or paid for is set in the extension profile

Comment: my extension is a paid version.So shall i need to upload package.xml and extension package.xml file during the extension submission?

Comment: Sorry For accepting your answer as much delayed @edmondscommerce